# What is this spider I found in Idaho?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

I live in Moscow, Idaho and saw this guy early in the morning last week. It was about quarter sized if I recall. I've never seen one before and was in a hurry so I couldn't get a better picture, sorry.

Comment: Looks like female mouse spider. But "Fangs" missing!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a black trapdoor spider (I'm guessing male by the size of the abdomen), check out the photos on the page I've linked below and see what you think - and this is a pretty good picture, usually the photos friends send me are far more blurry!

http://www.spiderzrule.com/trapdoor1.htm